# Parsing OpenDocument Spreadsheets (*.ods)

Tags: java, opendocument

I wonder if there is a tool/lib with friendly API for parsing such documents. I guess I'm looking for some analogy of *Apache POI*, which supports *OpenOffice* documents.

Does anybody know such a tool?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the Apache ODF toolkit together with SimpleODF:

http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/simple/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think it'll fit to my purposes.

Comment: Did anyone use this?